# the ui doesn't update correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, listview, flutter-listview

in this i made an list that has data and i give it to the listview.builder
my problem is when i want to delete the secound map with the _removeFromList
it deleted from list but the listview.builder doesnt display it correctally

like its

323 mb   in first  ,

5.49 mb  in secound ,

405  mb  in third,

when i deleted the secound map its like this =>

323 mb   in first

5.49 mb  in secound

and its all wrong,when i deleted the secound  map it should show me like this

323 mb   in first ,
405  mb  in secound ,

```
     List<Map<String, dynamic>> _myList = [{size : 323},{size:4.49},{size: 405}];


       void _saveList() async {
       // print('Before getting SharedPreferences instance');
       SharedPreferences prefs = await              SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       // print('After getting SharedPreferences instance');
       List<String> myListString =
      _myList.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();
      // print('the data is saved');
      prefs.setStringList('myList', myListString);
      }


     // load myList
     void _loadownloadManagerist() async {
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     List<String> myListString = prefs.getStringList('myList') ?? [];
     setState(() {
     _myList = myListString
     .map((item) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(item)))
     .toList();
      });
      }

     // remove the map from myList
     void _removeFromList(int item) {
     setState(() {
    _myList.removeAt(item);
    _saveList();
    _loadownloadManagerist();
    });
    }




     Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        

          return DownloadingCardMain(
          
            UrlSize: _myList.isNotEmpty ? _myList[index]['urlSize'] : 0,
          
    
          );
        },
      ))
```

when i close the program and run it again

it show me the correct one

but i want when i deleted the secound one this happend

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling `_removeFromList` function?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in those three lines

```
 _myList.removeAt(item);
 _saveList();
 _loadownloadManagerist();
```

`_saveList` and `_loadownloadManagerist` both do asynchronous code (`futures`), meaning they creates a thread that do some work, but does not wait for it to finish, and execute the next line.

So in your case, when you call `_saveList`

- it runs the code inside it
- faces an `async` code, so it execute that in a different thread, and continues the program, ***(note it does not continue in the same function, the rest of the function execution is stopped till that async(future) finishes)***,
- when continuing the program, it goes and run the next function, which is `_loadownloadManagerist`.

So what is done here is that you load the list before you actually update it in sharedPrefs

What you need to do is to await for the `_saveList` future to complete, by `await`ing it, simply by adding an `await` before the function. you must also change that function to return a `Future`.

so the code will be something like this:

```dart
Future<void> _saveList() async {
       
       SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       List<String> myListString =_myList.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();
      // await this function to finish
      await prefs.setStringList('myList', myListString);
      }


     // load myList
     Future<void> _loadownloadManagerist() async {
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     List<String> myListString = prefs.getStringList('myList') ?? [];
     setState(() {
     _myList = myListString
     .map((item) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(item)))
     .toList();
      });
      }

     // remove the map from myList
     Future<void> _removeFromList(int item) async {
     _myList.removeAt(item);
    // await this future to finish before executing the next line
    await _saveList();
    await _loadownloadManagerist();
     setState(() {

    });
    }
```